# How can I delete the "Drupal" text?

Tags: blocks

I have tried to go in to the inspector mode and I find the string and delete it, but when I refresh, it is still there. I have tried to empty the cache as well. I don't know how to save my changes and I do not find a way to delete the text through any options in the more graphic interface. I am not good at coding.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: i posted two images. click the ]2 for the second

Comment: The inspector mode is only for debugging. If you were able to change the site's code, you could be able to hack any website.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to adjust your *site branding name* or the whole block.

### Modify

Change the value in *Configuration  > System > Basic site settings: Site name* and save.

### Hide/delete

If you actually want to take it out, you can remove the *Site branding* block from the active theme region (*structure > block layout*).

### Modify/delete on theme level

Move core/modules/system/templates/block--system-branding-block.html.twig to your custom theme and modify/delete specifically `{{ site_name }}` which hold the site name.